# How to overcome the Gamma function limitation in R

Tags: r, function, math

I'm trying to compute the **following formula**:

[image]

**in R using:**

```
nu = 343  ## !! can be any other number but this is the max. R can handle !! ##

gamma(nu / 2) / (sqrt(nu / 2) * gamma( (nu - 1) / 2) )
```

**Question:**

I just realized that `nu = 343` is the max for `nu` that R can handle. I was wondering if there is a way I can overcome this limitation so that R can handle any value for `nu`?

Comment: The usual trick is to use `lgamma()` for larger arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Use the log-gamma function `lgamma` which returns the (natural) logarithm of the gamma function. So for the ratio you'll have a difference of log-gammas.

Comment: Write G(n) = exp(log(G(n)) and then figure out how log(G(n)) is a difference of log-gamma values. Then take the exponential of whatever you figure out and you're all done.

Comment: @user138773   Shouldn't that be `lgamma(nu / 2) - log((sqrt(nu / 2)) - lgamma( (nu - 1) / 2) )`

Comment: For what value of nu is it NaN?

Comment: I had bad typing. Misplaced parens.  Should be `lgamma(nu / 2) - log(sqrt(nu / 2)) - lgamma( (nu - 1) / 2)`

Comment: There you go! Thanks, Gosh have forgotten all the High school algebra !

Comment: Argh.  Also it is wrong.  lgamma uses natural log and by default log is log base 10.    You _really_ need `lgamma(nu / 2) - log(sqrt(nu / 2), base=exp(1)) - lgamma( (nu - 1) / 2) `

Comment: Thanks, yes, I took care of that by taking `exp()` of what you had written previously.

Comment: in R, `log()` is **not** base 10 by default.